# Momentum commutation relations in QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

Given the following relations for scalar fields at equal time $t$:

$$ [\phi_{\alpha}(x) , \pi_{\beta} (x')] = i \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta( x - x') $$

$$ [\phi_{\alpha}(x) , \phi_{\beta} (x')] = [\pi_{\alpha}(x) , \pi_{\beta} (x')] =0 $$

and the definition of momentum:

$$ P_j = -i \int d^3x \pi_{\alpha} (x) \partial_j \phi_{\alpha} (x)$$

how can we show that:

$$ [P_j , \pi_{\alpha}(x) ] = i \partial_j \pi_{\alpha}(x)  \hspace{0,5cm} (1) \hspace{0,5cm} ?$$

By plugging the definition of the momentum operator I got to:

$$ [P_j , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]  = -i \int d^3x [ \pi_{\beta} (x) \partial_j \phi_{\beta}(x) , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ] $$

$$ [P_j , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]  = -i \int d^3x  \pi_{\beta} (x) [ \partial_j \phi_{\beta}(x) , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]$$

but what do I do to arrive at $(1)$ from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can always integrate by parts, i.e.
$$ [P_j , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]  = 
i \int d^3x [ \partial_j \pi_{\beta} (x) \phi_{\beta}(x) , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]$$
and now use that $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$. Namely
$$ [P_j , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]  = 
i \int d^3x \partial_j \pi_{\beta} (x) [ \phi_{\beta}(x) , \pi_{\alpha}(x') ]$$
and now use the equal time commutation relations to get the right answer.

I hope this helps!

**Remark:** I think I can spot some minor error in your definition of $P_j$. One should include a sum over $\alpha$ or at least state that the Einstein summation notation is implicit, otherwise you can not avoid having $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ in your final answer!